Cauchy reduction formula with measure (a variation)
The Cauchy reduction formula conveniently compresses $n$ integrations of a function $F(x)$ into a single integral. Here I am interested in reducing the following "curved-space" generalisation:
\begin{align} 
& \int_0^x \cdots \alpha (x_5)\int_0^{x_5} ~\int_0^{x_4} \alpha (x_3)~\int_0^{x_3} ~\int_0^{x_2} \alpha (x_1)~F(x_1)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n
\end{align} which may be viewed as promoting $\int \int d {x_1} d {x_2} \to \int \sqrt{g(x_1,x_2)} d {x_1} d {x_2}$ with measure $\sqrt{g(x_1,x_2)} \equiv \alpha(x_1)$.
I find it straightforward to show (for $n=2$)
\begin{align} 
\int_0^{x_3} ~\int_0^{x_2} \alpha (x_1)~F(x_1)\,dx_1 dx_2 
& =   \int_0^{\sigma(x_3)} ~(x_3-\sigma^{-1}(t))F(\sigma^{-1}(t)) dt
\end{align} where $\sigma(x) = \int_0^x \alpha(x') dx'$  has inverse $\sigma^{-1}(x)$.
Q: Is it possible to reduce, $e.g.,$ the $n=4$ case
\begin{align} 
& \int_0^{x_5} ~\int_0^{x_4} \alpha (x_3)~\int_0^{x_3} ~\int_0^{x_2} \alpha (x_1)~F(x_1)\,dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4
\end{align} to one integration?
p.s.  If
\begin{align} 
\alpha (x_1)= {1\over 1-\lambda x_1} \ , ~~ F(x_1)=x_1
\end{align}
where $\lambda$ is a constant parameter, I found that, curiously, the following formula appears to be true:
\begin{align} 
& \int_0^x \cdots \alpha (x_5)\int_0^{x_5} ~\int_0^{x_4} \alpha (x_3)~\int_0^{x_3} ~\int_0^{x_2} \alpha (x_1)~F(x_1)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n  \\
&=  -\frac{i^n}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)^2} \int_0^{\sigma(x)} \kappa(t)^{{n\over 2}-1} (x-\sigma^{-1}(t))^{n\over 2} F\bigl(\sigma^{-1}(t)\bigl)\,dt 
\end{align}
\begin{align} 
\sigma(x) =-\frac{\ln(1-\lambda x)}{\lambda } \ , ~~ \sigma^{-1}(t)= \frac{1-e^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda } , ~~  \kappa(t)=  \frac{1-e^{\lambda  t}}{\lambda }  . 
\end{align}
(And I think it is correct for general $F(x_1)$.) Unrestricted to the above particular choices of $\alpha(x)$ and $F(x)$, I wonder if there is an expression of $\kappa(t)$ in terms of $\sigma(t)$ more generally. (By choosing other special cases of $\alpha(x)$ and $F(x)$, I found $\kappa(t) \neq \sigma^{-1}(-t)$.)
The more symmetric case with $ \int d {x_1}  \to \int \sqrt{g(x_1)} d {x_1}$ was considered in this post.

Please don't keep making inconsequential edits. Every time you do so, it is bumped to the top of the front page. The software has flagged this question for (roughly) too many edits, and since you only asked this yesterday, that's fairly impressive, and not in a good way. Just a word of advice.

@DavidRoberts I see. Thanks!

I can reduce the four-fold integral to two integrations:
\begin{align} 
& \int_0^{x_5} ~\int_0^{x_4} \alpha (x_3)~\int_0^{x_3} ~\int_0^{x_2} \alpha (x_1)~F(x_1)\,dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4\\
%&=\left(\prod_{i=1}^4\int_{0}^\infty dx_i\right)\theta(x_5-x_4)\theta(x_4-x_3)\theta(x_3-x_2)\theta(x_2-x_1)\alpha(x_3)\alpha(x_1)F(x_1)\\
&=\int_0^{x_5}dx_1\int_{x_1}^{x_5}dx_3\,(x_5-x_3)(x_3-x_1)\alpha(x_3)\alpha(x_1)F(x_1).
\end{align}
I don't see how this can be reduced to a single integral for arbitrary functions $\alpha$ and $F$.
